# MBProgress HUD method return value

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i've implemented MBProgressHUD but what im trying to do is to with this line of code call the `MakePost` method which is boolean and if the method posted correctly returns a `YES` and if not `NO`

```
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(MakePost:) onTarget:self withObject:@"1" animated:YES];
```

if the return value is `NO` i'd like to show an alert

```
UIAlertView* cError = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error try later!" message:@"Post Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[cError show];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method:

```
/**
 * Shows the HUD while a block is executing on a background queue, then hides the HUD.
 */
- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block completionBlock:(MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock)completion;
```

Follow the comments in code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

   // setup our alert we use UIAlertController instead of deprecated UIAlertView 
    self.alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Alert"
                                                           message: @"Hey are you ok ?"
                                                    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 // we will store the result of the method "makePost" lowercase ;)
    __block BOOL result;

  // setup the HUD
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";

    [hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
     result =  [self MakePost];
    } completionBlock:^{

        if (result)
        {
            NSLog(@"OK");
        }
        else
        {
              [self presentViewController: self.alertController animated: true  completion: nil];
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: showAnimated whileExecutingBlock method is deprecated in the latest version